# Emacs, "helm-grep-do-git-grep" ---> git --no-pager grep

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.

I want to use command **helm-grep-do-git-grep** to find text in many files.
But when I start (in git folder) this command I get error:

**git --no-pager grep...**

Here screenshot:[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the git command in a terminal?  You should probably be in the same directory as you are in the `dired` buffer.  I'm guessing there are actually no results, which would mean it's working correctly.

Comment: what git command I need to run in this folder?

Comment: the one in the git grep buffer in your screenshot.

Comment: From terminal I run command: 

git --no-pager grep -niH --color=always --exclude-standard --no-index --full-name -e "https" -- d:/Personal/TODO/
 
But no result. Nothing happen.

Comment: Well there you go: the git command isn't returning anything.  Is the string "https" actually in any of the files?  If the string is in some files, are they being ignored with .gitignore?  This is clearly not an Emacs or helm problem.

Comment: In my 2 org files I has text "TODO". I try this command from terminal but nothing happen:  git --no-pager grep -niH --color=always --exclude-standard --no-index --full-name -e "TODO" -- d:/Personal/TODO/

Comment: It has something to do with your git repo, git config, Windows, etc.  The command works for me.

Comment: I fix the problem. You was right. The problem was in git client. Before I use "cygwin/bin/git.exe" - and it's not work for my command. So I download Git client from here https://git-scm.com/download/win  - and now my command work from Emacs and from terminal. Thank you.